# only part of dictionary logging in script

Tags: javascript, dictionary

I've created a dictionary in my program (it is a news app which retrieves articles from an API) and early on in the program I have created a dictionary of the default sources, including the name they should display under and their ID.

```
var defaultSources = [{
  id: 'the-telegraph',
  name: 'The Telegraph',
  id: 'bbc-news',
  name: 'BBC News',
  id: 'buzzfeed',
  name: 'Buzzfeed'
}]
console.log(defaultSources)
```

But the console only logs

```
    {id: "buzzfeed", name: "Buzzfeed"}
```

This gives me some problems later on in the code as the dictionary only saves this one news source. Any suggestions as to why this is happening?

Comment: What should I replace it with?

Comment: The code is literally one line after the other. Later the problem is once it is established that the user is not logged in it pushes the dictionary into a function which adds them to a nav bar and then into a function which gets the news for the first one, but it gets news for buzzfeed which is the third one: updateSources(defaultSources)
   getNews('https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?sources=' + defaultSources[0].id + '&apiKey=ec50393d07f94e0080db971780b931b4')

Comment: You have an array with one object in it. That object duplicates the same property names. Property names in a single object must be unique. End result is only the last id and last name are available in the object

Comment: Wrap each `id` and `name` property in it's own object literal. `var defaultSources = [{id: 'the-telegraph', name:'The Telegraph'}, {id:'bbc-news', name: 'BBC News'}, {id: 'buzzfeed', name: 'Buzzfeed'}];`

Comment: break it up into an array with multiple objects `[{id:1,name:'..'},{id:2,name:'...'}]`

Comment: Thank you so much! Sorry a little new to coding, much appreciated.